# Cannot setup Google App Engine plugin with IntelliJ

Tags: google-app-engine, intellij-idea, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to install and configure Google App Engine on my IntelliJ Ultimate IDE. I've installed with Google App Engine plugin, but I'm unable to link it to my Google Cloud account in ***Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Google App Engine***.

Specifically, when I add my Google Cloud credentials and click 'Apply', the Apply button just sticks. I can click 'OK' to clear the dialogue box, but when I go back into Preferences, the details have not been applied and I'm just back at a blank screen.

There isn't any code to share, but I've attached a screenshot, showing a thick blue border around the Apply button. I've tried different IntelliJ versions on different laptops, with the same result.

Can anyone help?

**Before. Apply button 'stuck'**

[image]

**After. Going back into Google App Engine, the details have not been applied**

[image]

Comment: Are there any exceptions in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085)? Please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA. StackOverflow is not a JetBrains bug tracker =)

Comment: Hi. Yes I've already filed a bug with YouTrack, but who knows how long that will take to get addressed. Thought I would ask here as well, in case anyone had any workarounds.

Comment: You have contacted support team and support engineer has reproduced the problem and submitted a bug on your behalf: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-261854. Please follow the ticket for updates. It's unlikely that you will get a solution here.